# jQuery .load div id conflict

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using links in an HTML template to load HTML files(e.g. inc_1.html and inc_2.html) as per below code. These HTML files are very similar forms which have the same div and checkbox id's. The purpose of each form is to calculate the cost of a service. JavaScript and jQuery is used to do the math. Users check the items they want using a checkbox and they get a total cost.

```
 <script> 

  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a#f1').click(function(){
            
            $('#tutitionPane').load( 'inc_1.html' );
        });

        $('a#f2').click(function(){
            
            $('#tutitionPane').load( 'inc_2.html' );
        });
   
    });
    </script>
```

...as the user clicks on a link e.g. `<a id="f1" href="#">form1</a> or <a id="f2" href="#">form2</a>`
it loads the html file into a `<div id="#tutitionPane"></div>` in the main template.
The problem is that the first form they click on all the calculations they make are correct but the second form they click on the values are off. I assume there's conflicts with the id's and values being set by interactions with the first form that was loaded.
Can I use an `unbind`method or something to reset the files as they get loaded into the main template? A forced refresh of the page would work but i don't want to do that.

The gist of the main template is like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <title>Samp</title> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/switch.min.js"></script>
<script> 

  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a#f1').click(function(){
            
            $('#tutitionPane').load( 'inc_1.html' );
        });

        $('a#f2').click(function(){
            
            $('#tutitionPane').load( 'inc_2.html' );
        });
   
    });
    </script>
</script>
  </head>
  <body class="py-4">
    
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <a id="f1" href="#">form1</a>
        <a id="f2" href="#">form2</a>
            
         <div id="tutitionPane"></div>
     
    </div> 
          
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sample js calc:

```
function t1() {
    tuition = tuition === 0 ? 53498 : 0;
    document.getElementById('t1').innerText = '$' + tuition;
    document.getElementById('t1-total').innerText = '$' + tuition;
    document.getElementById('total').innerText = '$' + (tuition + activity + program + orient + health + laboratory + room * roomMonths + personal * personalMonths + education * educationMonths + transport * transportMonths);
  }
```

Any advise appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Where are you doing calculations?

Comment: You shouldn't get duplicate IDs, because each `.load()` completely replaces the HTML that was loaded by the previous one.

Comment: <script src="js/switch.min.js"></script>

Comment: If there's a variable holding the total of something, you need to set it to `0` before each calculation.

Comment: What does `switch.min.js` do?

Comment: Hardly browser caching?

Comment: Do the HTML files change dynamically? Use a cachebuster in the URL.

Comment: I just added some of the js. Unchecking checkboxes reveal the prices and values and totals are placed in divs.

Comment: Yes I need to set variables back to their original values each time I call a file to the main template

Comment: Was hoping it just involved a line of code in `$(document).ready(function () {` I need to reset these: `let tuition = activity = program = orient = health = laboratory = room = personal = education = transport = roomMonths = personalMonths = educationMonths = transportMonths = 0;`

Comment: Put `tuition = 0` before the `.load()` call.

Comment: There's no way to automatically reset all the variables, nothing keeps track of which variables are used by which scripts.

Comment: Barmar adding tuition = 0 does fix it for 1 field. I guess I have to make all fields = 0 before each load call? Would unbind or unload method help? Thanks

Comment: Yes. You could put a function in `reset_vars()` function in your script that sets all the relevant variables to `0`, and call that before each `.load()`

Comment: Getting bombarded with warnings about long comment threads. Thanks very much! I added `tuition = activity = program = orient = health = laboratory = room = personal = education = transport = roomMonths = personalMonths = educationMonths = transportMonths = 0;` and that works